# Chain Increment Operators

Tags: c#, operators

Why can you not chain operators?

```
int test = 5;
test++++;
```

OR

```
int test = 5;
++test++;
```

This code gives a compile time error.

> The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer.

I fully understand this, *if allowed*, would be a complete code smell and has almost no real world usage. I don't fully understand why this results in an error. I would almost expect the value of `test` to be 7 after each statement.

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand which part of the spec prohibits it, or why it was designed that way?

Comment: Is there any language that allows that ?

Comment: @JonSkeet : why it was designed that way ?

Comment: @JonSkeet A bit of both I guess. The only usage I can actually see would be to replace `i = i + 2` in a for loop.

Comment: @Habib: Yes, C++ does (only the prefix version, though, with a maximum of one postincrement).  See for example http://rextester.com/OVXB28335

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's due to section 7.6.9 of the specification:

> The operand of a postfix increment or decrement operation must be an expression classified as a variable, a property access, or an indexer access. The result of the operation is a value of the same type as the operand.

The second sentence means that `i++` is classified as a *value* (not a variable, unlike `i`) and the first sentence stops that from being the operand of the operator.

I suspect it was designed that way for simplicity, to avoid weird situations you really don't want to get into - not just the code you've given, but things like:

```
Foo(ref i++);
i++ = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `++` operator works on a "left hand value" i.e. something one can assign to, because it is equivalent to:

```
test = test + 1;
```

On the other hand `test++` is an expression, you can't assign something to it, test++ = 5 does not work.

This is the reason that `(test++) ++` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

++ is a special operator that's just a shorthand of foo = foo + 1.  There's no point in creating an infinite list of overloads like +++, ++++, etc. when you can just say foo = foo + 7, which is what would have to be done.

- on its own is an operator that joins 2 values.  If language designers tried to make pull double duty as a special syntax like you're suggesting, that'd be an extra burden on the compiler and may lead to some confusing code.

So basically the short answer is it's just not worth the effort.  It's not that hard without it, especially with the += operator.  And it's more readable.  What's easier to read:

```
int test = 1;
test+++++;
```

Or....

```
int test = 1;
test += 5;
```

Counting all those plus signs would be a pain to read.  2 is clear to see.  More than that and you're headed toward counting jelly beans in a 50-50 raffle. :-)

Comment: I think the OP means applying the `++` operator a second time like `(i++)++`, not why the language doesn't have `+++` or `++++` operators.