# Is increment stackable? I.e x++++; or (x++)++;

Tags: c++, increment, post-increment, decrement, pre-increment

When me and my friend were preparing for exam, my friend said that `x+++;` is the same as `x+=3;`

It is not true but is `x++++;` same as `x+=1;` or is `(x++)++;`? Could I generalize it? I.e. `x++++++++++++++;` or `((((((x++)++)++)++)++)++)++;` is equivalent to `x+=7;`

Maybe it's completely wrong and it is true for `++++++x;` or `++(++(++x));` equivalent to `x+=3;`

Also it should generalize to `--x;` and `x--;`

Comment: Why didn't you try this in a compiler before posting this question? Don't listen to your friend, listen to your compiler.

Comment: @Lundin: On the other hand, compilers have been known to accept non-standard code.

Comment: ^ Here's [a good site for playing w/compilers](https://godbolt.org/) be sure to select whatever compiler the course uses

Comment: My friend just made fun. But this emerged from my deep thoughts. I currently don't have access to a compiler

Comment: If you need more than `++`, then use `+= value`.

Comment: It depends on `x`. For fundamental types like `int` the expression `x++` is an rvalue and you can't increment it further but `++x` is an lvalue and can be stacked. For class types it depends on how they implement the operator.

Comment: For `(x++)++;` and similar, recall that the postincrement operator returns the value previously held in `x` prior to incrementing it. So `(x++)` is actually a pure rvalue and you can't call `operator++` on it anyway--it'd be like expecting `5++` to be meaningful. `(++x)` returns an lvalue reference to `x` and can be chained.

Comment: The post-increment operator returns a **prvalue** copy of the original operand, and prvalues cannot be used as input to that operator; so, stacking **post**-increment is not possible. However, the **pre**-increment operator returns a reference to the (now modified) operand, so those can be stacked. Thus, `++++++x;` is equivalent to `x += 3;`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859460/chain-increment-operators

Comment: @NathanOliver: Related, I suppose, but that's about C#.

Comment: Try this: `int ZZ, Z2 = ZZ = 22, SS = - - ZZ -- - - -- -- Z2;` can you predict what `std::cout << SS << std::endl;` will show, after that?

Comment: @JRBros If you have access to the internet, you have access to a compiler. Godbolt.org for example.

Comment: No my friend just didnt understand it well.

Comment: Goldbolt.org is not good in small screens

Comment: I would be more interested in this case: `int i = 4; cout>>++i++>>endl;`, is it 4 or 5? :-)

Comment: I think it probably won't work work since postfix don't go well in stacking

Comment: @FredLarson Lol.  Didn't even notice that.  google lied to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of your program can be understood using the following rules from the standard.

From [lex.pptoken#3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.pptoken#3.3):

> Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the **longest sequence of characters** that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail, except that a header-name is only formed within a #include directive.

And from [lex.pptoken#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.pptoken#5):

> [ Example: The program fragment `x+++++y` is parsed as `x ++ ++ + y`, which, if `x` and `y` have integral types, violates a constraint on increment operators, even though the parse `x ++ + ++ y` might yield a correct expression.  — end example ]

---

> is x++++; same as x+=1;

Using the statement quoted above, `x++++` will be parsed as `x++ ++`.

But note that from [increment/decrement operator's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

> The operand *expr* of a built-in postfix increment or decrement operator must be a modifiable (non-const) **lvalue** of non-boolean (since C++17) arithmetic type or pointer to completely-defined object type. The **result is prvalue** copy of the original value of the operand.

That means the result of `x++` will a *prvalue*. Thus the next postfix increment `++` cannot be applied on that prvalue since it requires an *lvalue*. Hence, **`x++++` will not compile**.

Similarly, you can use the above quoted statements to understand the behavior of other examples in your snippet.